# SVG to PNG to AJAX API post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg

I have a rather large and complex code of SVG that generates using JavaScript and jQuery dynamically based on the pages information.

I then have an AJAX post save.

What am I failing to do  to convert this to post the image data properly?

```
var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
var string= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
base64=string.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
var rid = kRid || "";
var fileN = " Product " + rid + ".png";
var req = "";
req += "<qdbapi>";
req += "<field fid='323' filename='" + fileN + "'>" + base64 + "</field>";
req += "</qdbapi>";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "text/xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  processData: false,
  //url altered 
  url: "https://removed.quickbase.com/db/removedDBID?act=API_EditRecord&rid=" + rid,
  data: req,
  success: function(responce) {
    //auto reload page
    var str = window.location.href;
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = str;
    }, 5000);
  }
})
```

The idea came from this snippet of code that I used else ware to get current PNG files and move them:

```
$.get(url, function(xml) {
  var promises = [];
  $("record", xml).each(function() {
        var url = $("f#9 url", this).text();
        xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var arrayBuffer = xhr.response;
            var base64 = btoa([].reduce.call(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer), function(p, c) {
              return p + String.fromCharCode(c)
            }, ''))
            var req = "";
            req += "<qdbapi>";
            req += "<field fid='6' filename='" + name + "'>" + base64 + "</field>";
            req += "<field fid='54' >" + Rid + "</field>";
            req += "<field fid='44' >" + comment + "</field>";
            req += "</qdbapi>";
```

... then the AJAX post.

I do not have access to do this via PHP.

Comment: You shouldn't blindly append "==" to the end of the base64 string. Base64 encoding implies that 3 src characters turn into 4 output characters. When the input length isn't a multiple of 3, it's padded so that it is, using NULL (0x0). See more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_Padding

Comment: Was not blindly I used the ajax script I had before to look at about 10 other files whose format is png and logged them to console, every one of them had the "==" at the end.

Comment: by blindly, I mean without checking the input stream length. That all the files you checked had `==` on the end is mere chance. Depending on the actual degree of compression used, 2 pngs with the same dimensions can obviously have different lengths and thus, padding requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I forgot to add == to mark the end of the file so:

```
var string= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
string+="==";
base64=string.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
```

and huzza it works...